# probability and applied statistics 2

Tags: probability

the probability of success of three student X,Y and Z in the one examination are 1\5 ,1\4 and 1\3 respectively . find the probability of success of at least two .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The probability that both $X,Y$ succeed is $\dfrac{1}{20}$, for $X,Z$ is $\dfrac{1}{15}$, and for $Y,Z$ is $\dfrac{1}{12}$.